# Building dlib - #include <string> not found

Tags: python, c++, cmake, dlib

I'm trying to install [howdy](https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy) which requires [dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib) to be installed system wide. However, `cmake` fails to build with some basic headers not found (stack excerpt below).

I managed to replicate the same error by simply calling `sudo pip3 install dlib`.

What I did:

- I used to have Howdy installed and working perfectly before.
- For some unrelated reason, I uninstalled python system-wide, which broke a lot of things (gnome in particular)
- Managed to reinstall most stuff, but not howdy

What is weird is that **I can install and use dlib without a problem in userspace (`pip3 install dlib`)**.

Truncated stack trace:

```sh
Installing collected packages: dlib
...
   Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- -j4'
    Scanning dependencies of target dlib
    [  2%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_2.cpp.o
    [  2%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_1.cpp.o
...
/tmp/pip-install-x10yjhu1/dlib_eaecabb22c5e4734b842455a6d752d55/dlib/bigint/../algs.h:93:10: fatal error: string: No such file or director
       93 | #include <string>       // for the exceptions
          |          ^~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
...
        7 | #include <iosfwd>
          |          ^~~~~~~~
```

One possibly related warning in the stack before the error:

```sh
Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
    -- Found CUDA, but CMake was unable to find the cuBLAS libraries that should be part of every basic CUDA install. Your CUDA install is somehow broken or incomplete. 
Since cuBLAS is required for dlib to use CUDA we won't use CUDA.
```

The only hint that I've found so far is that it might be trying to compile with `gcc` rather than `g++` ?

Comment: What OS are using?  You may find this useful https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/22/install-dlib-easy-complete-guide/

Comment: Linux - Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks, I think I've read it already but I'll check!

Comment: Well, didn't help :/